# RazorPDF not working on build server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, itext, nuget-package, sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm creating an application which uses the RazorPDF nuget package for creating PDF document. When using this on a local development pc everything works fine but when I deploy on a server, I always get the standard error: "Error. An error occurred while processing your request."

Do I need to change properties in my project to make the nuget package work on a server except the normal way to deploy or has any one got experience with this?

Comment: Don't know much about this particular package, but with other PDF generators problems like this are caused by the permissions of the application pool user that the web application is running under.

Comment: Solved, some one merged my part of the project with his and forgot to include the new files.